# Linkedlist in C can copying the whole nodes to ptemp

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct nodetag{
    int ndata;
    struct nodetag *pNext;
};
typedef struct nodetag nodetag;

int main(){
    nodetag *p1=NULL,*bago,*last,*ptemp;
    int i,x,y;

    printf ("\nEnter number of nodes: ");
    scanf ("%d", &i);
    y=i;

    while (i)
    {
        if (p1 == NULL)
        {
            p1 = malloc(sizeof(nodetag));
            last = p1;
            p1->pNext = NULL;
            scanf("%d",&p1->ndata);
        }
        else
        {
            bago = malloc(sizeof(nodetag));
            last->pNext = bago;
            bago->pNext = NULL;
            scanf("%d",&bago->ndata);
        }
        i--;
    }

    ptemp = p1;
    for(x=0;x<y;x++){
        printf("%d",ptemp->ndata);
        ptemp=ptemp->pNext;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

can i copy the whole nodes to ptemp to avoid the pfirst getting moved?
when i ran the code it seems that it only prints the first and last data of the nodes.
how can i access the second node when the number of nodes is more than 2?
im focusing on printing the data in the nodes

```
ptemp = p1;
for(x=0;x<y;x++){

    printf("%d",ptemp->ndata);
    ptemp=ptemp->pNext;
```

this seems that it crashes the whole program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bago->pNext = NULL;`

After this add this line:

`last = bago;`

Now errors in your code:

1. You are not updating the `last` pointer hence every time you assign a value it is overwritten on the second value assigned.
2. You have never `free`d the `malloc`d memory, before exiting `main()` free all the memory by iterating over the list as you do while printing.
3. `getch()` is not a standard library function, hence not portable, you should use `getchar()` instead.

**EDIT**: (On OP's comment)

Well, try to understand it yourself, its very simple. Step over/Execute the code manually by hand.

Comment: yup thanks now i understand it goodthing you pointed out the "last" pointer

Answer (score 2):

```
else
     {
      bago = malloc(sizeof(nodetag));
      last->pNext = bago;
      bago->pNext = NULL;
      scanf("%d",&bago->ndata);
      last = last->pNext;  /*you need add this statements*/
      }
```

sorry ,my English is not good.
I can not explain it in English.